# Call function multiple times with different attributes

Tags: angularjs

Hi I'm relatively new in angularjs and I try to create dice roller app.

I have controller with 3 functions (`$scope.rollDice`, `$scope.markDice`, `$scope.checkMarkedDice`). I want to use `$scope.rollDice` multiple times with different attributes - independently. I would like to know how to modify them to work on some OOP approach. Not sure about the them. In my case if I hit button **Roll 4d6** in 1st row, 2nd row is also affected and vice versa.

I guess I need to transfer my rollerDice function to factory or maybe directive. But I'm not sure how to manage it.

I can imagine to transfer `$scope.checkMarkedDice` to be var function of `$scope.rollDice` but I don't know how to handle `$scope.markDice` which has to be call from `index.html` so it need to be `$scope` or not?

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TKquvq?p=preview)

Comment: I think you should pass `$index` reference to your function instead of `dice`

Comment: ^ indeed, pass the index into the function and change your `$scope.result=[];` to `$scope.result=[[],[]];` so that you can refer to each roll separately with `$scope.result[index]`. Here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kNCuE8lmKcV7N9qtEG1k?p=preview)

Comment: Using the @AlekseySolovey suggestion, check here  http://plnkr.co/edit/a8V9QPFZJrTNad5zVmfR?p=preview

Comment: Thanks it works. What if I would need do it more dynamically? Let say I don't know how many diceRoller I will need and what should be length of result array. Should I transfer it to directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally AngularJS is not OOP, therefore you should store individual objects in the arrays and refer to them with **index**.

I have made what you have requested. (**Warning:** Heavy Snippet, here is a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/N6jzqutK5O722Pjw7ymx?p=preview) instead)

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('myCtrl', ["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.dice_ = [
      [1, 6, 4],
      [1, 6, 2]
    ];
    $scope.result = [
      [],
      []
    ]; // SPECIFY SIZE / LENGTH HERE (currently: 2 items)

    // Roll the dice
    $scope.rollDice = function(min, max, count, index) {
      var i = 0,
        result = [],
        markedDice = $scope.checkMarkedDice(index);

      if (markedDice.length === 0) {
        while (i < count) {
          result[i] = {
            number: Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min,
            class: "dice"
          };
          i += 1;
        }
      } else {
        while (i < count - markedDice.length) {
          result[i] = {
            number: Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min,
            class: "dice"
          };
          i += 1;
        }
        angular.forEach(markedDice, function(dice) {
          result.splice(dice.index, 0, dice);
        });
      }
      $scope.result[index] = result;
    };


    // Mark the dice
    $scope.markDice = function(dice) {
      if (dice.class === "dice") {
        dice.class = "dice marked";
      } else {
        dice.class = "dice";
      }
    };


    // Chceck if any dice is marked
    $scope.checkMarkedDice = function(index) {
      var marked = [];
      angular.forEach($scope.result[index], function(dice, $index) {
        if (dice.class.indexOf('marked') > -1) {
          dice.index = $index;
          marked.push(dice);
        }
      });
      return marked;
    };

    $scope.addDice = function(min, max, count) {
      $scope.result.push([]);
      $scope.dice_.push([min, max, count]);
    }

    $scope.removeDice = function() {
      $scope.result.pop();
      $scope.dice_.pop();
    }

  }]);
}());
```

```css
.dice {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  float: left;
  width: 46px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 46px;
  border: 1px solid #585858;
  border-radius: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: #4573b9;
}

.dice:hover {
  background-color: #4573b9bd;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.marked {
  background: #00466f !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Test freez reroller</title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Basic Table</h2>
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr class="flex-row">
          <th class="col-md-3">Type</th>
          <th class="col-md-3">Action</th>
          <th class="col-md-6">Result</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="flex-row" ng-repeat="d_ in dice_ track by $index">
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="rollDice(d_[0],d_[1],d_[2],$index);">Roll {{d_[2]}}d{{d_[1]}}</button>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div ng-click="markDice(dice);" class="{{dice.class}}" ng-repeat="dice in result[$index] track by $index">{{dice.number}}</div>
          </td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
    1: <input type="number" ng-model="a1"><br> 2: <input type="number" ng-model="a2"><br> 3: <input type="number" ng-model="a3"><br>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="addDice(a1,a2,a3)">Add</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="removeDice()">Remove</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```